# RefreshControl issue in Two tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using two tableview in my project now i want to add UIRefreshControl for both tableview. but it's working with only one table.

Can anyone help me out, Here is my code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;

//.m

refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing"];

[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];   // not working
[self.tableView1 addSubview:refreshControl];  // This will work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually `Objective-C` worked as interpretor, so it will execute the last statement, thats the reason `[self.tableView1 addSubview:refreshControl];` the final one is working

```
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];   // not working
[self.tableView1 addSubview:refreshControl]; // working
```

for example if you alternate this

```
[self.tableView1 addSubview:refreshControl];   // not working
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];    // working
```

so in here you need to create another one

```
refreshControl1 = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl1.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
refreshControl1.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing"];

[refreshControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self.tableView1 addSubview:refreshControl1];
```

Comment: @MayankPatel -- you can implement in alternate ways also use tags of tableview you can use single `UIRefreshControl`

Comment: i am alredy using the tags of tableview how can i set ?

Comment: @MayankPatel -- if want a single refershcontrol at a time use whenever u refresh the table on that time just add like if (tableview.tag==1) {[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];}